# How to determine a conditional distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Consider: $$X\stackrel{d}{=}N(\mu, \sigma^2)\qquad Y\mid X \stackrel{d}{=}N(\alpha+\beta X, \tau^2) \qquad U\mid Y,X \stackrel{d}{=} N(0,\nu^2)$$
>
> Determine the distribution of $W=X+U$ given $Y$ and $X$.

How should handle this problem? Could someone give me some pointers?

Should I start with $\mathcal{P}(W<w\mid X,Y) = \mathcal{P}(U<w-X\mid X,Y)$? (what then?)

Dus $U\mid Y,X \stackrel{d}{=} N(0,\nu^2)$ imply $U$ independent from $Y,X$ since the distribution does not contain $X,Y$?

Comment: $U$ is *conditionally* independent given $X,Y$, but that does not imply $U$ is independent of $X$ and $Y$ separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X+U<w|X,Y)=P(U<w-X|X,Y)=\Phi\left(\frac{w-X}{\nu}\right)$

Since we know $X$, its distribution is irrelevant, and it just modifies the point we evaluate the distribution of $U$.

In other words, $X$ and $Y$ are now just *constants*, not random variables, and we already know how $U$ behaves when we know $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: And that implies $W \stackrel{d}{=} N(X,\nu^2)$ right?

Comment: @dietervdf yep!